# C mutating struct properties by reference

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-management, typedef

I'm learning pointers in C and i came across a confusion between ***pointers X struts X functions***

**The goal:** creating two structs and mutate properties inside them.

**The path I'm going:** I am creating these two structs and then passing its memory addresses to the mutate function, the function then prints and mutates some properties of these structs.

**Result I get:**

**1:** The name of the struct created is nod being entirely printed and its of the wrong struct passed, and the life property is not properly changed and printed to the screen.

**2:** On the terminal I get "Segmentation Fault", not sure why but I'm pretty sure its something wrong I did.

***Here's my code:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int power;
    int life;
    char name[];
} Hero;

void attackHero(Hero *hero, int *power) {

    (*hero).life = (*hero).life - *power;

    printf("Damage: %d\n", *power);
    printf("Attacked hero: %s\n", (*hero).name);
    printf("Hero's remaining life: %d\n", (*hero).life);

};

int main () {
    Hero flash;
    flash.power = 250;
    flash.life = 500;
    strcpy(flash.name, "The Flash");
    
    Hero batman;
    batman.power = 380;
    batman.life = 700;
    strcpy(batman.name, "Batman arkham knight");

    attackHero(&flash, &batman.power);

    return 0;
}
```

**Result printed to the terminal (Vscode + gcc):**

[image]

Comment: The struct `Hero` has a "flexible array member" so you must allocate memory for the struct. `Hero flash;` and `Hero batman;` are no good, because they have a zero-length array. In this usage, that struct member should be (say) `char name[64];`

Comment: Unlike other programming languages, strings in C do not do memory management for you. So a declaration like `char name[]` isn't magically going to allocate memory for the string, and `strcpy` doesn't allocate memory either. You're going to need to get a good book on C, and study how strings work.

Comment: Understood @WeatherVane, but instead of declaring [64], how would I allocate memory for the struct when creating it? for example flash.name = malloc(64);

Comment: The `->` operator is your friend.  Re-write `(*hero).life` as `hero->life`.

Comment: You don't allocate space for `flash.name` directly, instead you do something like `Hero *flash = malloc(64 + sizeof *flash)`.

Comment: You will almost certainly want to add a `size_t` member in the struct to record how much space you've allocated for the flexible array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the warning that I get when I compile your original code:

```
1.c:25:2: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 10 bytes into a region of size 0 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   25 |  strcpy(flash.name, "The Flash");
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1.c:30:2: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 21 bytes into a region of size 0 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
   30 |  strcpy(batman.name, "Batman arkham knight");
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you want to use the flexible array then you have to allocate space for it like this:

```
int main () {
    Hero *flash = malloc(sizeof(*flash) + sizeof("The Flash"));
    flash->power = 250;
    flash->life = 500;
    strcpy(flash->name, "The Flash");

    Hero *batman = malloc(sizeof(*flash) + sizeof("Batman arkham knight"));
    batman->power = 380;
    batman->life = 700;
    strcpy(batman->name, "Batman arkham knight");
    attackHero(flash, &batman->power);

    free(flash);
    free(batman);
}
```

Here there the resulting code refactored a bit, and I added a error check for malloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int power;
    int life;
    char name[];
} Hero;

Hero *createHero(int power, int life, const char *name) {
    Hero *h = malloc(sizeof(*h) + strlen(name) + 1);
    if(!h) {
       printf("malloc failed\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    h->power = power;
    h->life = life;
    strcpy(h->name, name);
    return h;
}

void attackHero(Hero *hero, int power) {
    hero->life -= power;
    printf(
        "Damage: %d\n"
        "Attacked hero: %s\n"
        "Hero's remaining life: %d\n",
        power,
        hero->name,
        hero->life
    );
};

int main(void) {
    Hero *flash = createHero(250, 500, "The Flash");
    Hero *batman = createHero(380, 700, "Batman arkham knight");
    attackHero(flash, batman->power);
    free(flash);
    free(batman);
}
```

Alternatively use a fixed array (`char [64]` as suggested by @Diego) or a `char *` and allocate space to it.  The former only needs 2 lines of code change from the original:

```
// largest name in use
#define NAME_LEN sizeof("Batman arkham knight")

typedef struct {
    int power;
    int life;
    char name[NAME_LEN];
} Hero;
```

Comment: The first option is what i'm going for, that solves my problem since i still get the dynamics I wanted thanks

Comment: Cool.  I have minor refactoring in a few minutes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Whole lotta malloc() going on. Since the hero’s names are string literals (and assuming they don’t change), just change name[]; to const char *name in the structure and initialize via simple assignment:

```
flash.name = "The Flash";
batman.name = "Batman arkham knight";
```

No worries about malloc() failures, name sizes or free() requirements.